# Why adclick.g.doubleclick.net listens on all ports

Tags: network, ports

I have `adclick.g.doubleclick.net` listening on all ports. When I launch an application like Starcraft 2, for example, it is listening on localhost. Or for some applications, there was a connection from my hostname to remote address: `adclick.g.doubleclick.net` which is google server.

I thought doubleclick.net concerns only Chrome and web advertising. What does it have to do with other software installed on the computer? I already blocked it by mvphosts, but I am curious.

Comment: " I have adclick.g.doubleclick.net listening on all ports. " what does that mean? Care to show what commands you typed and what results did you see? (As text, not as images)

Comment: Would you mind rewriting your question? It's currently hard to understand, and hard to know what issue your have.

Comment: Both the battle.net launcher and the Starcraft 2 menu have browser elements that call home. Home, being battle.net, includes doubleclick.net on their website, and so the browser element fetches that too.

Answer (score 4):

My guess: you modified your hosts file to include `0.0.0.0 adclick.g.doubleclick.net` or `127.0.0.1 (same)` as a way of preventing webpages (or maybe apps) from accessing that site, likely because you don't like advertising or consider it a privacy violation.

As a result, when tools like `netstat` etc try to display something that is using address 0.0.0.0 (which is actually the special value `INADDR_ANY`) or 127.0.0.1 (which is actually the loopback address used for `localhost`) they end up displaying the bogus name you assigned to that address. Try `netstat -n` to turn off name translation and see what is actually going on.